# Create sequence numbers based on location of line features using Arcobjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#, geometry, line

I want to add a Sequence number property for line features (Pipe), which will hold a value that will determine where the line is in respect to other lines that are attached to the from point and to point.

Here is a picture that will provide a better explanation.
[image]

So based on the picture above, AB1 sequence would be 0, AB2 sequence would be 1, and AB3 sequence would be 2

This is the class presenting the lines

```
  internal Pipe(IFeature pipe, Ipoint fromPnt, IPoint toPoint){
      Shape=pipe.ShapeCopy;
      PipeOid=pipe.Oid;
      FromPoint=fromPnt;
      ToPoint=toPoint;
    }

    public int PipeOid;
    public int SequenceNumber;
    public IPoint FromPoint;
    public IPoint ToPoint;
    public Polyline Shape
```

What i have tried so far.
Looping over a list of Pipes, and using QueryNormal from the middle of each line,and passing the length in a positive and a negative value, so I can get results in both directions, in the picture it would be from top and bottom of line. Then I would check if the normal if it touches other Pipes that are connected to the nodes, and based on those results, I would get my sequences.

```
foreach(pipe in commonPipes){
var pipeShap=pipe.Shape;
 ILine normalLine;
 pipeShap.QueryNormal(esriSegmentExtension.esriNoExtension, 0.5,true,10,normalLine);
 // test for if normalline touches anything, 
 pipeShap.QueryNormal(esriSegmentExtension.esriNoExtension, 0.5,true,-10,normalLine);
 // test if it touches anything 
 }
```

I found it rather long to do so, and that the positive and negative lengths are sometimes reversed. Also the length of the normal could fall short of touching the links below or on top.

I tried creating a point in the middle of each line, and then using ProximityOperator, or just plain X,Y but that is also long since the line could be horizontal or vertical.

Any ideas in the Arcobjects that might help me solve this problem ?

Comment: How do you decide which is 1, 2 or 3? Is the first encountered line from A to B AB1, sequence 0, and then each subsequent incremented as encountered in the iteration or is it that the middle line receives a value and the left is minus 1, right plus 1? Assigning numbers based on endpoints arbitrarily isn't too difficult, it was much easier in ArcINFO, but isn't too hard in .net working out left and right relationships is a bit more difficult, especially as lines can be in reverse orientation (B to A) which fuddles up the left/right relationship.

Comment: Basically the left line is the starting line, so no matter how they are placed or flipped. The leftmost line will always have the sequence of 0, and the right most will have (the number of lines -1 sequence). that leaves the lines in between the leftmost and rightmost.

Comment: The problem is that 'leftmost' and 'rightmost' utilize direction of travel, all lines start and end but if a line is starting at B and ending at A left and right are flipped. To simplify this you would need to nominate a direction A to B with a logic of how to decide if an end is type A or B... lowest X, lowest Y or lowest OID of coincident point are methods that I have used before. Once you have done that you can ReverseOrientation on any lines with the ToPoint closer to A than FromPoint then using the first segment of each line get the Angle (in radians) and sort clockwise.

Comment: I just remembered a left/right test that I have used previously in C++. It uses a vector dot product V1.V2 which is negative when the V1 is left of V2. The first segment from A is considered a vector (magnitude and direction) and as they all have the same starting point you can find the dot product of all other possibilities, the first one being *left of all others*, remove from list, add to sorted list and repeat until only one remains being the *right of all others*. Read more https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43897/determining-if-something-is-on-the-right-or-left-side-of-an-object